# Inject configuration file (IoC) with execution modes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, inversion-of-control, autofac

I have appsettings.json (and appsettings.development.json behind) in the ASP.NET Core project. I want inject the configuration file depending the **execution mode** (production, development...) like Core does, but I want access to the JSON across **different projects**, using **IoC**.

Using the Core's DI, I have:

```
config.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: false)
.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environmentName}.json", true, true)
.AddEnvironmentVariables();
```

And I inject IConfiguration in every controller.

Ok, using Autofac I have tried adding a file link to the JSON in another project (where the IoC container is located) and testing the next code:

```
configurationBuilder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

//configurationBuilder.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: false)
//.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environmentName}.json", true, true)
//.AddEnvironmentVariables();

var module = new ConfigurationModule(configurationBuilder.Build());
builder.RegisterModule(module);
```

And:

```
this.container.Resolve<IConfiguration>();
```

But I get the next error:

> The configuration file 'appsettings.json' was not found and is not optional. The physical path is 'C:\Jhon\source\Workspaces\Project\Development\Application\Api\Api\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\appsettings.json'.

Comment: `different projects` Do you mean different web project or class library project?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your code have troubles with searching location of your `appsettings.json` file during the dependecies root configuration.

As I see, the easiest solution is switching file's `Copy to Output directory` setting to `Copy Always`.

But I have a few more things to tell.

**First one**. If you're using ASP.NET Core 2.x you don't need to write

```
config.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: false)
.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environmentName}.json", true, true)
.AddEnvironmentVariables();
```

Because `BuildWebHost` can do all stuff for your

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();
```

**Second one**
I suppose that using raw `IConfiguration` isn't a good idea. I'd rather prefer [options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.0) pattern. It helps us to divide our logic and code which extracts settings from `IConfiguration`.

Comment: I'm saying how I do with Core and DI, but the problem is I need create a IConfiguration instance from other projects below the API (they can't access to the API layer), and then inject them with Autofac.

Comment: @JhonDuck so, You just need to configure a path to your appsettings files.  I faced the similar case a few months ago. And as the result I wrote an article about it http://egorikas.com/asp.net-core-shared-configuration/